# Rails using :mem_cache_store like :file_store

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm storing objects in `:file_store` with `Rails.cache.write` and getting them back with `Rails.cache.read` and all is working fine.

Now when I replace `:file_store` with `:mem_cache_store` , I start getting strings instead of objects.

I would like to have the same behavior with `:mem_cache_store` as `:file_store`

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found dalli, which is a CacheStore that works perfectly with memcached :-)

https://github.com/mperham/dalli